# Youtube video embedded in UIWebView has no sound on real device

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios9

This is how I embed my video. It has sound in the simulator, however has no sound on a real device (iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)) Xcode 7.1.1.

This is the code I use to play it:

```
if let youtubeID = youtubeID {
    let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(youtubeID)?playsinline=1\" width=\"\(width)\" height=\"\(height)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
    cell!.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    cell!.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
    cell!.webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true
    cell!.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

    cell!.webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
}
```

Comment: I have done like above and video is playing, but (in window mode) the player's seek bar is not very smooth. have you faced such issue?

Comment: Please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404583/seekbar-fast-forward-not-working-smoothly-ytplayer-iframe-api-in-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer myself: Here the solution:

```
        if let youtubeID = youtubeID {
            let embededHTML = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style type=\"text/css\"> body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } body, html { height: 100%; width: 100%; } </style> </head> <body> <iframe id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(youtubeID)?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body></html>"

            cell!.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
            cell!.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
            cell!.webView.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true
            cell!.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
            cell!.webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
        }
```

Comment: I have done like above and video is playing, but (in window mode) the player's seek bar is not very smooth. have you faced such issue?

Comment: I have posted a new question regarding this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404583/seekbar-fast-forward-not-working-smoothly-ytplayer-iframe-api-in-ios

Answer (score 14):

Most developers come across this issue they forget to
**switch on the ringer button on the left side of your iPhone**.
It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks man. Made such a fool of myself.
Your answer should be on the top.

Comment: Sometimes we forget the main features of iPhones while developing the apps.

Answer (score 8):

SWIFT 2.0 version I have the same problem for me the solution was to add in the AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)  
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)  
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

This enable sound in my UIWebView

Comment: The second do block{} stopped some videos from playing. When I deleted it, it worked!! Just use the first do block{}